# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory. Python not reading files correctly

Tags: python

I am having some troubles when trying to open a file in the same directory. When I open the file it brings me up this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/joseph/Desktop/direct path/test_path.py", line 3, in <module> 
with open("nba_reports.csv","r") as file:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: nba_reports.csv
```

When in reality that file named 'nba_reports.csv' is right next to where the python file is saved. I have had this problem in various different IDEs, I'm currently working on Visual Code and Visual Studio and I have managed to solve the problem by specifying the complete path from the file as "c:/Users/joseph/Desktop/direct path/nba_reports.csv". However, when I open this same code on Thonny it does recognize the file with no problem at all just by specifying the file name. I would really appreciate if someone could help me out with this problem so that I can just write the file name on Visual Code.

The code is as followed:

```
with open("nba_reports.csv","r") as file:
    for row in file:
        print(row)
```

Comment: What is your current working directory? Try `import os;print(os.getcwd())`/

Comment: `import os` `print(os.getcwd())` prints `C:\Users\joseph`

Comment: Is the file in that directory? Assuming you haven't `os.chdir`'d somewhere and the file is in that directory, the code should work.

Comment: No, I am working on "`c:/Users/joseph/Desktop/direct path/`" but the directory return up until Desktop as `C:\Users\joseph`. Any way to get the complete path?

Comment: Paths are a challenge and how you set them depends on your goals for the script. A hard coded full path as in "c:/Users/joseph/Desktop/direct path/nba_results.csv" can be rasonable if your script only wants to work with that one file. Alternately, IDE's should let you set current working directory when running a script.  Yet another alternative is to get the path as a command line variable in `sys.argv` and set that parameter properly when you run the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the os library to get the current working directory with

```
os.getcwd()
```

It's likely if you print the result of that, it will show Python isn't using the proper working directory. To change it. use os.chdir() as follows. The parameter you should give os.chdir follows the way you would use the cd command from the command line in a Unix based operating system.

```
>>> import os
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/myname'
>>> os.chdir('./Documents')
>>> os.getcwd()
'/Users/name/Documents'
```

Comment: I tried using this code when researching over the forums, but didn't work for me or at least the directory wasn't the one I needed. I tried uninstalling python and running the installer again, I left all as default (express installation) and the problem was still there.

Comment: How should I use the `os.chdir()` method so that I can get the directory that I am looking for?